# Start spock test from jar on server without installed groovy

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I implemented some spock test in groovy. I built a test jar, that include this test. Now I want to run it on server. Server knows nothing about spock or groovy. I decompiled the jar to get valid name for my test fuction. The following it is:

```
/* Error */
@org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureMetadata(line=65, name="connect via jdbc", ordinal=0, blocks={@org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockMetadata(kind=org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.WHEN, texts={}), @org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockMetadata(kind=org.spockframework.runtime.model.BlockKind.THEN, texts={})}, parameterNames={})
public void $spock_feature_0_0()
{
   ...
```

So, looks like, valid name to start the test function is `$spock_feature_0_0`. I can upload my test jar on server. How I can start the test fucntion on server?

Comment: You need groovy to run groovy bytecode

Comment: @tim_yates - Thank you. I have not groovy on the server, but I can upload any number of jars to it. So, if I get all requred jars, could I run groovy bytecode?

Comment: Yes, provided those jars are made available on the CLASSPATH when the code is run.

Comment: @tim_yates - Do you know, how I can get the list of required jars?

Comment: clear your maven repository, run only tests, check your maven repo - there will be only jars that you need to run them. Combine them with groovy's and that should do the work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Maven project, there is no need to clean your whole local repo like *Georgi Stoyanov* said. Just call `mvn dependency:tree` on your project in order to see something like this:

```
...
[INFO] +- de.scrum-master:test-resources:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.1-groovy-2.4:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.7:test
[INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.2.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5.1:test
...
```